# 'DataFrame' object is not callable in google colaboratory

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

do this in google colab and i get the following error

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv')
col = df('Fare')
print(col)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('titanic.xlsx')
col = df['Fare']
print(col)
```

Comment: Can you confirm that this resolved your issue? Without an explanation it’s unclear how this relates to your original question.